# Can't change the name of an activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

Tried everything i could find on internet but cant seem to find a way to change the name of an Activity. When i test it it just shows the application name.

AndroidManifest

[image]

Comment: You can use "Refactor" on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write label tag in activity tag not between activity tag

like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="label_name(eg>@string/~~">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, try `android:label` attribute:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="your_activity_readable_name">
```

According to [android:label](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#label), if the attribute is not set, the label set for the application as a whole is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setTitle(int titleId)
```

or

```
setTitle(CharSequence title)
```

on your `onCreate()` in Activity that you want to change the label